# Cask beer at home

Tags: packaging, techniques, equipment, keg

Anyone have a good source for getting smaller versions of a firkin for home use?
I am interested in casking some beer at home for parties and special occasions.

Are there any good links out there for using a corny keg as a cask?
I am thinking of doing gravity feeding as I don't want to invest in a proper beer engine to pull beer up through a tap.

Comment: Nice for the 15 characters Dean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK we have access to 5L mini-kegs -> http://www.the-home-brew-shop.co.uk/acatalog/Easy_Kegs.html I don't know if you can get these in the States or not, but they're prefect for parties. Or if you want something a bit bigger, then there are things like -> http://www.barleybottom.com/menu/product/&ID=204

Answer (score 1):

I have used the Pig for almostcask ale. It's okay. It goes flat within about 2 days, so I wouldn't let it sit around for much more than 48 hours. The restrictor plate could probably come out, and since there's no way to compress the container you probably need to keep the hand pump around to introduce a little pressure into the pig so the liquid can flow out.

But I did quite enjoy the beer and would do it again.

If you want a more novel solution, read about using polypin containers. These are very popular in the UK, which is famous for it's plastic storage vessels.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [Party Pig](http://www.partypig.com/)?  I've never used one, but it looks like it would be a good alternative.  They make it sound like each one holds a little over 2 gallons, so I'm not sure if they would be big enough for you, but it's an option.

Comment: Call me picky..but I'd prefer to put my beer in stainless for the look and quality of a real cask.  But the party pig is a good idea.

Comment: I agree, it's not too visually pleasing.  It kind of reminds me of the Coopers and Mr. Beer kits.

Comment: The Pig is actually pretty cool. I used one for a few batches before I jumped into kegging for real. Its great if you can't invest the $$$ or space into a real kegging setup. To use it as a cask, you would maybe leave out the inflatable pouch thing and just let the natural carbonation push out the beer? Some guys drill a hole in the side and fit it for a small CO2 cartridge, but for all that work, you might as well figure out how to keg.